# Performance optimization multipliers

Tags: optimization, architecture, micro-optimization

Can anyone provide an example of a system in which a performance improvement of x% to a single sub-component of the system results in an overall performance increase of Ax% (where A>1) for the entire system?  In other words, can there be a positive multiplier effect for localized optimizations in a system?

I could have sworn that I have encountered such performance multiplier effects in the past, but for the life of me, I cannot construct even a hypothetical example of such a case.

Comment: That's not theoretically possible.  If you get say 20% improvement in something that takes 50% of overall time, the entire process will only improve 10%.

Comment: @Eric, I think I may have gone off into the weeds on this question.  I must have been thinking of a situation in which there was unnecessary blocking in a parallel system and elimination of the blocking resulted in substantial performance improvement.  I just don't think I could accurately characterize the elimination of that blocking as an "x% performance improvement in a sub-component."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to get a multiplier effect in software performance (without different hardware) is to exploit [*Amdahl's Law*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) which just says if you make something take less time it's faster. (Boy, that's pretty deep.)
If you reduce the time the software takes by a fraction X, then you have given it a speedup ratio of R = 1/(1-X).
For example, if a program takes 100 seconds, and you manage to shave off 60, then you're left with it taking 40 seconds, which is 100/40 = 2.5 times as fast as it was.

Here's how X and R are related:

```
X    R
0.0  1
0.1  1.11..
0.2  1.25
0.3  1.43..
0.4  1.66..
0.5  2
0.6  2.5
0.7  3.33..
0.8  5
0.9  10
0.99 100
1.0  inf
```

Also, these effects compound.
If you reduce time by 50%, the speed is multiplied by 2.
If you take the result of that, and reduce *its* time by 50%, the speed is multiplied again by 2.

Notice that the second 50% was only 25% of the original time.
The first time reduction made the second one bigger, by a factor of 2 !

[*Here's an example*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1870/1262) where that speed-compounding magnification effect produced a speedup of 730 times.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  I just covered Amdahl's Law for a parallel design, so I should have remembered that.

Answer (score 1):

The only example I can think of is in a system with some kind of hard real-time constraint, e.g. sub-component takes too long to execute, which results in a time-out and a re-try in some sort of I/O interface. Increasing the performance of the sub-component makes it fast enough to avoid the time-out + retry, thereby increasing overall performance significantly. Real-world examples that spring to mind are old skool disk controllers (before the days of cache etc) and network interfaces (time-outs result in packets being re-sent etc).